# Set properties for multiple breakpoints at once

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm debugging calls into a specific class, and have set a breakpoint on every function.

Converting these to tracepoints took some time and clicking, and now I'd like to extend the trace output. As I don't want to go through all breakpoints again, replacing the template, I wonder if there is a way to set breakpoint properties (such as the message printed) for multiple breakpoints in a single operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible change the default tracepoint message by modifying a registry key, but if you already have changed your existing tracepoints this wont help you.

The default message is (WinXP Visual Studio 2005) found at:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSA\8.0\Debugger\DefaultTracepointMessage - Function: $FUNCTION, Thread: $TID $TNAME**

Another solution would be to run a macro that loops through all breakpoints and modifies it's message:

```
    Dim bp As EnvDTE80.Breakpoint2
    For Each bp In bps
        bp.Message = "Your new output"
    Next
```

Comment: I think I'll go with the macro.